# How to return derivered type from method declared in base type

Tags: c#, .net, fluent, derived-class

I've a method in a base class that should return self instance of type as derivered type. For example:

```
class A
{
   public string X { get; set; }

   public A SetX(string x)
   {
       this.X = x;
       return this;
   }
}

class B:A
{
   public string Y { get; set; }

   public B SetY(string y)
   {
       this.Y = y;
       return this;
   }
}
```

Then I want to call methods fluently as below:

```
B b = new B();

b.SetX("x")
 .SetY("y");
```

But here `SetX` returns type of A, and A has'nt any method named `SetY`. How can I design such functionalty?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple different things you could do to achieve this.

The first is to use generics, using a type parameter to designate the real type of the instance:

```
public class A<T> where T:A<T>
{
    public string X { get; private set; }

    public T SetX(string x)
    {
        X = x;
        return (T) this;
    }
}

public class B<T> : A<T>
    where T : B<T>
{
    public string Y { get; private set; }

    public T SetY(string y)
    {
        Y = y;
        return (T) this;
    }
}

public class A : A<A>
{
}

public class B : B<B>
{
}
```

The second is to, in your `B` class, hide the method from `A` using the `new` keyword, like so:

```
class A
{
    public string X { get; set; }

    public A SetX(string x)
    {
        this.X = x;
        return this;
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public string Y { get; set; }

    public new B SetX(string x)
    {
        return (B) base.SetX(x);
    }

    public B SetY(string y)
    {
        this.Y = y;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first option is what I allready know and the second option is what I ask for. I think you should reorder the options to make it clear.

Comment: @HalilIbrahim I've changed the order like you asked. Glad it was helpful

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to declare `SetX` as a generic extension method:

```
public static T SetX<T>(this T a, string x) where T : A
{
    a.X = x;
    return a;
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
var newB = b.SetX("foo"); // returns type B
```

Comment: cool solution but in my stuation A an B are allready generic classes and I'm not able to resolve generic type parameters when using extenstion methods.

Answer (score 0):

use protected:

```
protected string X { get; set; }
protected A SetX(string x)
{
   this.X = x;
   return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
(b.SetX("1") as B).SetY("2");
```